# use induction to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k + 1) = \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3}$ for all $n ∈ N$.

Tags: summation, induction

I am supposed to use induction to prove that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{3}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am confused on how to go about this question, a step by step guide of this proof will be helpful.

Comment: It's easier to use binomial coefficients. $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) = 2\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+1}{2} = 2 \binom{n+2}{3} $

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ you get $2=2$

If true for n, then we know  $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k + 1) = [n(n + 1)(n + 2)]/ 3$$

Thus $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k(k + 1) = [n(n + 1)(n + 2)]/ 3 +(n+1)(n+2) $$

$$ = [n(n + 1)(n + 2) +3(n+1)(n+2)]/3 = [(n + 1)(n + 2)(n+3)]/ 3$$

Which is the statement for $n+1$

Comment: sorry, I saw only now that your answer came first: will cancel mine.

Answer (score 1):

That is a well known property of Rising Factorials.
To prove it by induction, we follow the standard steps.

a) the thesis is true for $n=1$

$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^1 {k\left( {k + 1} \right)}  = 2 = {{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} \over 3}\quad :\quad TRUE
$$

b) if it is true for $n$ it is true for $n+1$
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {k\left( {k + 1} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k\left( {k + 1} \right)}  + \left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{n\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)} \over 3} + \left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{n\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right) + 3\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)} \over 3} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)} \over 3} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {\left( {n + 1} \right) + 1} \right)\left( {\left( {n + 1} \right) + 2} \right)} \over 3}\quad :\quad TRUE \cr} 
$$

c) conclusion: the thesis is true for $1 \le n$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try iteration:

$1\times 2=2=\frac{2\times 3}{3}$

$1\times 2+2\times3=8=\frac{2\times3\times 4}{3}$

$1\times 2+2\times3+3\times 4= 20=4\times 5=\frac{3\times 4\times 5}{3}$

$1\times 2+2\times3+3\times 4+4\times 5= 40=4\times 5\times 2=\frac{4\times 5\times 2\times 3}{3}=\frac{4\times 5\times 6}{3}$

.

.

.

$1\times 2+2\times3+3\times 4+4\times 5 + . . .n(n+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$